# Agent pool selection on Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I have a long-running build I'd like sent to a self-hosted agent.  I've defined the pool with these agents in the Azure Pipeline.  The self-hosted agent is never selected.  How can I determine what is causing the Default pool to be rejected?

Answer (score 0):

you are most likely missing some of the needed programs\binaries on the agent to run these jobs (like nodejs, or java etc). If you go to `https://orgName.visualstudio.com/projectname/_settings/agentqueues` you can examine your agents capabilities. You might be missing some of those.

Also, if you queue build manually on your hosted agent it should tell you why it cant do that.